# Under the new Google Apps Marketplace OAuth 2 API Console, where are the IMAP and SMTP API?

Tags: gmail, oauth-2.0, google-apps-marketplace

With the old manifest system, I used MailAPI as a scope. It seems to have disappeared from the API list of the cloud console.

Comment: The new scope is `https://mail.google.com/` but this isn't available in the Google Developer Console's APIs pane.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SMTP and IMAP without turning on any services in Developer Console. Have you tried this and gotten an error?